# Twilio - How to retrieve the voice call recording media file by providing the call SID in NodeJs

Tags: node.js, twilio

I want to get the Twilio voice recording media file/url to play in my app, I am using [twilio-node](https://www.npmjs.com/package/twilio) package in nodejs.

```
let response = new VoiceResponse();
response.dial({
    callerId: process.env.TWILIO_NUMBER,
    record: true
    }, req.body.number);
    res.type('text/xml');
    res.send(response.toString());
```

I enable recording using above example and it is working, but the challenge is to get the media file by providing the call SID or recording SID through the API, I didn't found any example to fetch the recording SID or recording media file by providing the call SID.

```
let client = twilio(TWILIO_ACCOUNT_SID, TWILIO_AUTH_TOKEN)
let callLogData = await client.calls(callSid).fetch().then(data => { return data })
```

I can get the call log using above example, I tried multiple ways as per mentioned in the Twilio documentation, but I guess the package is not compatible with the documetation.  I have not use the programable voice but the direct call to person phone using Twilio.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

***Step 1:***

would be to ***"Get all recordings for a given call"*** as described here (https://www.twilio.com/docs/voice/api/recording-resource?code-sample=code-get-all-recordings-for-a-given-call-3&code-language=Node.js&code-sdk-version=3.x)

```
// Download the helper library from https://www.twilio.com/docs/node/install
// Your Account Sid and Auth Token from twilio.com/console
// DANGER! This is insecure. See http://twil.io/secure
const accountSid = 'ACXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX';
const authToken = 'your_auth_token';
const client = require('twilio')(accountSid, authToken);

client.recordings
      .list({callSid: 'CAXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX', limit: 20})
      .then(recordings => recordings.forEach(r => console.log(r.sid)));
```

---

***Step 2:***

once you have the recording ID (r.sid in the step above) you could for example ***get the .mp3*** for a recording with a GET request

```
GET /2010-04-01/Accounts/ACXXXXX.../Recordings/RE557ce644e5ab84fa21cc21112e22c485.mp3
```

as described here (https://www.twilio.com/docs/voice/api/recording-resource?code-sample=code-fetch-a-recording&code-language=Node.js&code-sdk-version=3.x)

---

***Note:***

The full URL to GET a recording's mp3 would be something like this:
`https://api.twilio.com/2010-04-01/Accounts/ACXXXXX.../Recordings/RE557ce644e5ab84fa21cc21112e22c485.mp3`

Comment: Thank you Alex. This is the perfect solution for me, I thought each call can have only one recording ID, so I didn't try the `client.recordings.list` to get the same, and why only this `/2010-04-01/` date?

Comment: That date (a `basePath`) is part of the Twilio's API base URL, it's not about the date of the call or recording.